# Infinite Cartesian Product of Sets with the Same Cardinality as $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: cardinals

Does anyone know what the cardinality would be for an infinite Cartesian product of sets that all have the same cardinality as $\Bbb{R}$? Thanks. I really do not understand the problem, so an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depends how infinite

Comment: As you’ve stated it, the problem is not well-posed: as **spaceisdarkgreen** said, if $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ is your family of sets that have the same cardinality as $\Bbb R$, and you’re forming $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$, the cardinality of this product depends on the cardinality of $I$.

Comment: What do you mean by how infinite?

Comment: This is the full question: Suppose A1, A2, . . . have the same cardinality as R. (There are denumerably many of them.) What is the cardinality of A1 ×A2 ×···?

Comment: @user770210 "denumerably many of them" is the answer to "how infinite?". (Brian Scott's comment is saying the same thing as I was saying, only more clearly.). You just said "infinite product"... it could have had more than countably many factors.

Comment: I really think this has to be a duplicate but I'll admit my quick search didn't yield anything. As a hint, what you want to compute is $|\mathbb R| ^{\aleph_0} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}.$ I imagine you have learned some rules of cardinal arithmetic that will help you simplify this expression.